# How do i make this roblox script (playerwhoclicked)?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to create a script for ROBLOX which would put a tool in the backpack of the player who clicked on a part. It is for a game which is going to be called ***Undead Nation***.

Comment: What did they click? A brick? A GUI? The mouse?

Answer (score 4):

ROBLOX has a `ClickDetector` object that allows scripts to detect clicks on a part through the `ClickDetector.MouseClick` event. One of the arguments passed to listeners to that event is the object of the player who clicked, so the listener may then put a tool in the backpack object in that player's object.

The following code, where `tool` is implied to be a variable referencing the tool object you want to put in the player's backpack (it will be cloned), should do roughly what you want if you put it in the part that should give a tool to the player when it is clicked:

```lua
-- Create a click detector in the part in order to be able to detect clicks.
local click_detector = Instance.new('ClickDetector', script.Parent)

-- Give the tool to the player when the button is clicked
click_detector.MouseClick:connect(function(player)
  local newTool = tool:Clone()
  newTool.Parent = player:FindFirstChild("Backpack")
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local door = game.Workspace.House.Door -- variable
local plank = door.Plank -- variable
local knob = door.Knob -- variable
local clickDetector = knob.ClickDetector -- variable

local function open() -- function
    plank.Transparency = 0.45
    plank.CanCollide = true
    plank.CanTouch = true
end

clickDetector.MouseClick:connect(open) -- runs function
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**